# Mixing HTML and Python code - how to refer to a changing filename within the HTML code

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to automate a process where I take a snapshot everyday but change the filename to that date. For example, I'd like to reference today's file as "20200219 snapshot.png" and change it to "20200220 snapshot.png" tomorrow. The problem is, I can't input the variable name *filename* after the img src and have to put in the hardcoded exact String.

```
date = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = date + " snapshot.png" 

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src="Directory/snapshot.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: Use an f-string? `html = f"""<html>...<img src="Directory/{filename}" /></body></html>"""`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse through the HTML DOM, use the [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) method to search for `img` tag. Then you can assign the src attribute value. The attributes are returned as a dict with the `attrib` parameter and you just need to look for the `'src'` key:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = date + " snapshot.png" 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src="Directory/snapshot.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
"""
tree = et.fromstring(html)
image_attributes = tree.find('body/img').attrib
for k in image_attributes.keys():
    if 'src' in k:
        image_attributes[k] = filename
html_new = et.tostring(tree)     
print(html_new)
```

Output:

```
b'<html>\n  <head />\n    <body>\n      <img src="20200220 snapshot.png" />\n    </body>\n</html>'
```

To pretty print this output, you can use the method provided in official docs [here](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint) and just do:

```
et.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```
<html>
  <head />
    <body>
      <img src="20200220 snapshot.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a string preceded by `f` and add your variable between `{}` to the string

```py
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = date + " snapshot.png" 

html = f"""\
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src="Directory/{filename}"/>
    </body>
</html>
"""

print(html)
```

Or use simple string concatenation instead

```py
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename = date + " snapshot.png" 

html = f"""\
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      <img src="Directory/"""
html += filename
html += """/>
    </body>
</html>
"""

print(html)
```